# Unity - Synchronize rename/refactor of GameObjects in hierarchy and scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to rename/refactor a GameObject in the Unity hierarchy as well as in all scripts where that GameObject should be found by a `GameObject.Find("x")` or a `Transform.Find("x")`?

I know that it isn't good practice to use `GameObject.Find()` in the first place, but for some static usages, where I can't assign gameobjects in the inspector, I need that.

I'm using Unity with Visual Studio, if that is of any importance.

Just for clarification: I've got a GameObject called "x" in the hierarchy (say a Button of the UI) and because my UI is static, the reference to x is static in my scripts. Now I want to rename "x" to "y", but if I do this in the editor the intuitive way, then the script fails to load, because it still tries to find "x".

Comment: Is the Gameobject only searched for once, and the reference remains consistent through the rest of the game, or does it need to be repeatedly called because what it returns can change during runtime?

Comment: Not that its helpful now, but if you finding yourself doing this in the future, stash that string literal as some static variable somewhere so when you run across this problem its easier to deal with.

Comment: I've build a whole game which is in the market already where I did this GameObject.Find tons of times. For some variables just once, for some even in the FixedUpdate method, which is a performance catastrophy now that my hierarchy got bigger and bigger.

Comment: If it's just to get a one-time reference to a Gameobject from multiple places, I strongly suggest having a centralized place where you cache a reference to it (maybe even make it a singleton so its easier to reference). You could define a manager class where you supply it a string to lookup with `Find()`, and store the value in a Dictionary for later lookups on the same name. And as per code11's suggestion, yeah - don't use the string literals in `Find()`, put them in a static variable somewhere (maybe in the manager class?) so you don't need to do a find/replace every time you change a name.

Comment: Yea, the latter idea is a good one for sure, but it doesn't fix the main issue. Refactoring in editor+script together must be possible somehow I'd say. Maybe using MonoDevelop?